# “can't find element ... of the list ... which is only of length” error in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on my thesis about solving a Traveling salesman problem with genetic algorithm. I use netlogo to solve the problem. But i got this error :

Can't find element 62 of the list

```
[7400 5100 5000 5000 2100 4300 5200 1200 900 4300 6000 6000 7600 5900 7600
 8600 7400 7100 6800 8100 3300 1400 1200 10400 8500 3700 11400 6900 2000 650
 0 3000 4900 9800 10600 4000 5200 7700 8500 5900 5000 7100 6100 6800 1000
 3200 2700 2900 1800 1300 9600 4800 4600 6700 7700 6100 4200 3200 9000 8200
 10500 13400],
```

which is only of length 62.
error while turtle 2 running ITEM
  called by procedure CALCULATE-DISTANCE
  called by procedure SETUP_1
  called by Button 'setup 1'

and i dont know why. Can someone help me about this?

Comment: turtle 2 tries to get access to item 62 of your list but your list consists of 62 items. As the index counting of list items in NetLogo starts with 0, the last element of your list has an index of 61. A list item with an index of 62 does not exist. Thats why you got an error message.